# Excessive cpu usage on certain websites

Tags: google-chrome, website

I have an issue similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1302265/1279295).

I have noticed it on my websites, but here's an example offender - https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/

I am using chrome on google. I tried the developer tools, but couldn't see anything like a crypto miner (*maybe I just don't know where to look*). What could be causing the issue?

Comment: the simplest method to eliminate the possibility of a crypto miners is to delete your Chrome user profile and see if the behavior continues to happen.  However, howtogeek is not compromised, and it does not distributed crytpominers.

Comment: It could also be a corrupt browser cache or javascript processing issue/memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

First, HowToGeek has java scripts running.

Second, there are many links to other sites, which might be running scripts, as well as HoToGeek, as shown in this screenshot from the uBlockOrigin extension:

[image: uBlockOrigin on HowToGeek.com]

Use an extension such as the above, either accepting it's default blocks, or using an additional block for all Javascripts (the button `</>`, showing 12 scripts may be blocked, in that screenshot). Some sites will not display correctly without *any* scriptng -- but some others actually display faster, and more cleanly.